# Resource Intensive Query

Tags: azure-sql-database, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using ado.net entities, against a SQL azure database. One of the queries is taking an extremely long time, most likely pulling data it doesn't need.  Is there a way to match up the query in C# with the query execution in Azure.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the query? The query shouldn't pull out data it doesn't need.

Comment: Its a LINQ generated query, that I build dynamically. I'm just trying to figure out in code where it is ran so I can simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

Please enable Query Store on SQL Azure to identify the T-SQL equivalent of the LINQ query. Use [this](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0010.htm) article for more details.

Below command helps you enabled query store

```
alter database current set query_Store on
```

Hope this helps.